# Sample python code for reading the resulting data when I click an ajax button in a webpage

Tags: python, ajax, web

I want to read the data in a webpage using python. I tried using selenium and mechanize but didn't understand either of them completely. Specifically, I want to read the details which appear when I click "My Package" in http://portal.acttv.in/group/blr/myaccount. Can anyone give me a sample code in python for this?

Comment: How much time have you put into learning Seleium? [This site](http://www.pushtotest.com/selenium-tutorial-for-beginners-blog.html) seems to offer a tutorial in interacting with a pages ajax. It could be useful.

Comment: I just did a surface search in selenium for any commands that might be useful. Let me try the site you mentioned. Thanks Austin!